# convert number to Cardinal in python

Tags: python

I want replace any number in String to Cardinal num then print it
I have one challenge: The user may not draw any spaces between the number and the next character
input:

```
1, we have to pay attention to 12 points!22
```

output:

```
1st, we have to pay attention to 12th points!22nd
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem without Python, i.e. with just pencil and paper?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may do this:

```
import re

s = '1, we have to pay attention to 12 points!22'
ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n//10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])
out = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda x: ordinal(int(x[0])),s)
print(out)
# 1st, we have to pay attention to 12th points!22nd
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually requesting ordinals [(not cardinals)](https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/language-lab/tricky-english-cardinal-numbers-vs-ordinal-numbers-when-should-you-use-which/).  You can use a dictionary for the suffixes and default the string to 'th' for numbers not ending in in 1,2 or 3 (except numbers ending in 11, 12, 13 wich do need a 'th' suffix):

```
def ordinal(n):
    suffix = {1:'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd', 11:'th', 12:'th', 13:'th' }
    return str(n)+(suffix.get(n%100) or suffix.get(n%10,'th'))
```

Output:

```
for n in range(1,25):print(ordinal(n))

1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
10th
11th
12th
13th
14th
15th
16th
17th
18th
19th
20th
21st
22nd
23rd
24th
```